# PATH problema persistente en un servidor con Python

Tags: python-2.7, servidor, rutas

Intento descargar Graphlab sobre un servidor con [el siguiente tutorial](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html). 
He descargadolo y programé con las herramientas y que había querido probar:

```
(gl-env)ubuntu@ip-172-hey-hey-hey:~/Eclipse-Stats$ source deactivate
discarding /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/gl-env/bin from PATH
ubuntu@ip-172-hey-hey-hey:~/Eclipse-Stats$ unset PYTHONPATH
ubuntu@ip-172-hey-hey-hey:~/Eclipse-Stats$ python Main.py 
2017-07-27 14:56:00.520425
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import prediction
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eclipse-Stats/prediction.py", line 1, in <module>
    from graphlab.toolkits.recommender import ranking_factorization_recommender
ImportError: No module named graphlab.toolkits.recommender
```

Es posible, [segun esta conversacion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62779/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-marine1), que sea un problema de PATH

Comment: Marine acabo de ver tu mensaje, estoy de viaje en la zona mas remota del planeta por lo visto y estoy conectado a GPRS a la increible velocidad de 30 kbps, tanto es así que no puedo ni abrir el chat.... :( Solo comentarte que si instalas GraphLab en un entorno virtual no puedes acceder al módulo desde fuera de este. Debes ejcutar el script desde dentro de ***gl-env***: `(gl-env)ubuntu@ip-172-hey-hey-hey:~/Eclipse-Stats$ python Main.py`

Comment: @FJSevilla Muchas gracias ! La respuesta esta `pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade graphlab-create` ! Muchas gracias para toda la ayuda ! Eres un genio !